# Laravel validation with lang for input names

Tags: php, validation, laravel, lang

I have one class named Validator that handles all validations that I need to do, and one class that extends my class with my rules and names for the error.

The problem is, I'm trying to use 'Lang' to get a translated message but it don't work and I don't know why.

Validation class:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Validators;

abstract class Validator {

    protected $data;

    public $errors;

    public static $rules;

    public static $names;

    public function __construct($data = null)
    {
        $this->data = $data ?: \Input::all();
    }

    public function passes()
    {
        $validation = \Validator::make($this->data, static::$rules, array(), static::$names);

        if ($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }
}
```

My class that extends the validator:

```
use Lang;

class PrestadorSiteValidator extends Validator {

    public static $rules = array(
        'nome'                  => 'required',
        'nome_fantasia'         => 'required',
        'email'                 => 'required|confirmed',
        'identificador'         => 'required',
        'pais_id'               => 'required',        
        'codigo_postal'         => 'required',
        'estado'                => 'required',
        'cidade'                => 'required',
        'rua'                   => 'required',
        'bairro'                => 'required',

    );

    public static $names = array(
        'nome'          => Lang::get('site.nome'),
        'nome_fantasia' => 'Nome Fantasia',
        'email'         => 'Email',
        'identificador' => 'CNPJ',
        'pais_id'       => 'País',
        'codigo_postal' => 'Código Postal',
        'estado'        => 'Estado',
        'cidade'        => 'Cidade',
        'rua'           => 'Rua',
        'bairro'        => 'Bairro',

    );


}
```

The error that I get:

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

When I try to use:

> 'nome'          => Lang::get('site.nome'),

Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, so maybe someone can suggest it "the Laravel way". Your issue in current code is that you try to use function call when defining a property. I'd suggest creating a method called inside a constructor to populate PrestadorSiteValidator::names (and switching from static access (the object is created either way so it shouldn't break too much things)).

Comment: Yes, I removed the 'static' from names, and initialized it empty.
I think I'll do the changes to populate the names in the constructor like you said. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute code in a PHP variable definition statement, so, instead of:

```
public static $names = array(
    'nome'          => Lang::get('site.nome'),
);
```

You must do something like

```
public static $names = array(
    'nome'          => 'site.nome',
);
```

EDIT:

To do what you need to do, the way you are doing it, you can, in your abstract validator, override an important method:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Validators;

abstract class Validator {

    protected function explodeRules($rules)
    {
        foreach(static::$names as $key => $value)
        {
            if (starts_with($value, 'lang::'))
            {
                static::$names[$key] = Lang::get(str_replace("lang::", "", $value));
            }
        }

        return parent::explodeRules($rules);
    }

}
```

Then use it:

```
public static $names = array(
    'nome'          => 'lang::site.nome',
    'nome_fantasia' => 'Nome Fantasia',
    'email'         => 'Email',
    'identificador' => 'CNPJ',
    'pais_id'       => 'País',
    'codigo_postal' => 'Código Postal',
    'estado'        => 'Estado',
    'cidade'        => 'Cidade',
    'rua'           => 'Rua',
    'bairro'        => 'Bairro',

);
```

Not a very clean way of doing it, but it should work.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing that out!
But the problem is that I need to call the Lang to get the translation, I can't think in a better way to do this :(

Comment: Edited to provide a way to do it.

Comment: Thank you man!
Worked like a charm! 
I calling this function inside my abstract validator. I Think it's easier that way.
I can't thumbs up your answer yet, but will do as soon as I can! :D

Comment: Oh, I simply overlooked the fact that you had an extension already, nice! No problem.